# How to detect if a method is called by unit test?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest

How do I detect if a method is called by unit test in ScalaTest?

Edit: sorry, I was expressing wrongly the thing I wanted. I have a code block in a method which takes very long to finish (I cannot mock it) and it does not affect any logic. I want to skip that code block in the unit test. So I want to know whether it is called by unit test or normal running. If it is called by unit test, I skip it, otherwise, I let it runs normally.

Comment: Have look at coverage tool such as scoverage SBT plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple workaround by adding a trait like this:

```
trait AppConfig {
  val isDebug:Boolean
}
```

use it in the places where I needs to check whether it is in debug mode:

```
class MyLogicClass {
  _: AppConfig =>
  def myMethod()={
    if(isDebug){...}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a code coverage library such as [scoverage](http://scoverage.org/) for instance. It will generate reports that indicate you which parts of your code are used by unit tests.